# LocomotiveCMS, ajax and pagination

Tags: ruby, locomotivecms

I'm using LocomotiveCMS on a project and I have some doubts on what's the best approach when dealing with ajax requests to the same site.

I have a Content Type for a model called reviews.  There can be plenty of review entries, so I'd like to show 20 per time, then allow fetching other 20s by hitting a button (like a 'load more' button).

What is the best approach for this?  I was thinking on making a custom API controller in order to do that.  It would have to find the right type of content entries based on the content type for reviews.  Then add some regular javascript that hits that controller and add the new set of reviews based on a mustache template.   Does it make sense or is there something that LocomotiveCMS has in order to accomplish such type of tasks?

**Update:**

I got an answer from the LocomotiveCMS google group.  Basically somebody suggested to create a liquid template that looks like a json.  For the full answer go to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/locomotivecms/vJKDtl81v7E/IEwOR9hhLjMJ